# Regex to find commas outside double quote in php

Tags: php, regex

What I have found so far is this

```
preg_match_all("/'[^']+'|[^,]+/", $input, $output);
```

Its supposed to find commas outside simple quotes, i need to adapt that to double quote.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that your original pattern for single quotes is correct, this one will find all commas outside double quotes:

```
preg_match_all('~"(?:[^\\\"]+(?:\\\.)*|\\\.)*+"(*SKIP)(*F)|,~s', $subject, $matches);
```

pattern details:

```
~
"
(?:            # all possible content between quotes
    [^\\\"]+   # all that is not a double quote or a backslash
    (?:\\\.)*  # eventual escaped characters
  |            #  OR
    \\\.       # an escaped character
)*+            # repeat zero or more times (possessive)
"              # closing double quote, can be replaced with (?:"|\z) or "?
(*SKIP)(*F)    # forces the pattern to fail and to not retry double quoted parts
|              # OR
,              # a comma
~
s              # allow the dot to match newlines characters
```

Note: if you want to consider the substring after an orphan double quote as a quoted substring (until the end of the string), you can replace the closing double quote in the pattern with `(?:"|\z)` or more simply `"?`

Note2: to reduce drastically the number of steps needed to find a match, the pattern can be rewritten like this:

```
~[^,"]*+\K(?:"[^"\\\]*+(?:(?:\\\.)+[^\\\"]*)*+"?|,(*ACCEPT)|\z(*COMMIT).)(*SKIP)(*F)~s
```

or if you want to use the first character discrimination technic:

```
~(?=[",])(?:"[^"\\\]*+(?:(?:\\\.)+[^\\\"]*)*+"?(*SKIP)(*F)|,)~s
```

Answer (score 1):

To match all the commas which was outside the single quotes and double quotes.

```
(?s)(?:(?<!\\)'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"])*")(*SKIP)(*F)|,
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/6)